# How to write the second value of custom operators array in Mathquill Editor

Tags: latex, react-quill, mathquill

i'm building graphical math formula editor using react **quill-editor-math** and i want to know How to write the second value of custom operators array in mathquill4quill Editor the first value is just normal latex but i can't figure out the second value. the documentation says  the second value is the latex that gets inserted into the MathQuill editor. here is the npm doc page
[MathQuill link that contains the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathquill4quill)

```
operators: [["\\sqrt[n]{x}", "\\nthroot"], ["\\frac{x}{y}","\\frac"]]
```

my question is i have this latex ["\x^b ","what to put here"]

Answer (score 0):

This second thing is what you write in latex to get this first thing, so it will be:

```
["\\x^b", "x^b"]
```